# Splitting PHP output into multiple pages

Tags: php, csv, split

I have installed a script to my website that displays simple news articles. On the backend there is a .csv fie containing all of the database - and the front end consists of this code (although I have changed it to suit my own website):

```
<?php  
//get news class and array  
include_once('newsadmin/includes/newsTools.class.inc.php');  
$newsTools      = new newsTools('csv/news.csv');  
$news_headlines = $newsTools->getNewsArray();  
//output news array as formatted html  
if (!count($news_headlines)>0){  
    echo '<p>There are currently no news headlines.</p>';  
}else{  
    foreach ($news_headlines as $key => $item){  
        list($news_id,$news_date,$news_title,$news_body) = $item;  
        $formatted_date = date('F j, Y, g:i a',$news_date);  
echo <<<HTML  
<a name="$news_id" id="$news_id"></a>  
<h3>$news_title</h3>  
$news_body  
<p><em>Posted: $formatted_date</em></p>  
<hr />  
HTML;  
    }  
}  
?>
```

I am trying to find a solution to split the news results over multiple pages - say a max of 10 news items per page. This would obviously create a set of links at the bottom of the page such as < **1** 2 3 >

I apologise if it's a lot to ask - but I've trawled google already and have only come up with solutions that deal with the issue for sites using MYSQL, whereas I'm not.

http://dev.pixxl.us/bwc/news.php

Thankyou.

Comment: You need to set some variables to keep the limit etc. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to research pagination. The work-flow should be like this
1) how many items you have?
2) how many you want to list per page?
3) with 1&2 defined, how many pages you have?
4) which page you are currently on?
5) what dataset should display based on 4?
6) prepare page links

```
# number 1
$total_items = count($news_headlines);

# number 2
$perpage = 10;

# number 3
$total_pages = ceil($total_items/$perpage);

# number 4 (you have to decide on the _GET parameter you are going to use, like page.php?page=2 etc.
$current_page = ($_GET['page'] == '') ? 1:$_GET['page'];

# number 5
$offset = ($current_page-1)*$perpage;
$news_headlines = array_slice($news_headlines,$offset,$perpage);

# number 6
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) echo '<a href="page.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
```